# Clearing TableView contents

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can any one help me by providing code for how to clear all the table view cell  contents.
The tableview when a button is pressed gets reloaded but does not get cleared

Thanks 
Rakesh

Comment: Combination of Legolas's answer and Neelesh's comment makes up your answer. Hope that helps you.

Comment: it would  have but i have lot's of arrays and they are interlinked so its not easy

Comment: Can you post that code so that I can check out the code and help you out??

Comment: Hi Parth. How to clear tableView after searching something? I mean, after searching items from search bar, when I click (x) close button of search bar, tableView should be also cleared. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 10):

For clearing a `tableView`, you just remove all objects from the array that is populating your table and you reload the tableView after that.

```
[myArray removeAllObjects];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: But i have to use the array values later so i cant clear it.I would like to have a solution with out clearing the array. Can u help???

Comment: copy the array into another one and use that as the data source

Answer (score 3):

Set a bool tableIsEmpty and set the number of rows in the tableview to either 0 (table is empty) or the arrays count according to this BOOl in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Of cousre you have to set tableIsEmpty = YES, when the button is pressed and to NO again when theres data loaded.
Then call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Not tested but should work shouldnt it?

Comment: I was about to give a similar solution. This will work if he knows the condition on which it should return 0. +1

Comment: Yeah, just add a BOOL property that tracks if cells should be cleared or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one variable as flag before reloading the table.

```
makeEmpty = YES;
[tableview reloadData];
makeEmpty = NO;
```

Then in the tableview delegate method

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  if(makeEmpty)
      return 0;
 }
```